# How to get screen coordinates of NotifyIcon in C# (Windows 10)

Tags: c#, wpf, taskbar, notifyicon

Is it possible to get the coordinates of any NotifyIcon in Win10?

I am trying to build a WPF application using C# and its screen position depends on these coordinates.

Comment: This would only make sense if you wanted to display a context menu or popup dialog. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: With wpf you normally dont use layout coordinates or anything like this. What are you trying to achive in the first place?

Comment: thank you for the replies, what I want to do is to create a transparent WPF, which is aligned to the NotifyIcon. The size of the WPF is small as the Notifyicon.

Comment: I don't really follow what you're trying to do but... Have you seen https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon-2  It is possible that part of the functionality in there is near enough what you want to achieve.